# committing calculated values to database from mvc3 controller

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3

I am wondering if what I want to do will be feasible in MVC3 Controller.  I have 3 tables; members, payment and paycategory.  I have  3 different payment categories in the categories table(CatA,CatB and CatC). In the payment view is a form for accepting member id and  payment value(decimal).  What I wish to do is when a value is passed through the form to the controller that value is split into 3 in a ratio and for each category the calculated value, and  the same  member Id is committed to the database.  For example if CatA is 30%, CatB is 50% and CatC is 20% and member Id is 1010 and 100.00 is passed on to controller,  the following should be committed to the database

> pId |  mId  |  catid | value
>
> 1  | 1010  |  1     | 30.00
>
> 2   | 1010  |  2     | 50.00
>
> 3   | 1010  |  3     | 20.00

Any leads or help of any kind will  be much appreciated.
controller

```
    // POST: /AutoPay/Create
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Create(AutoPay autopay, int tcd, int id, int tzid, FormCollection formCollection)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
                
         string[] rawpaysplit = formCollection["PayCatSplit"].Split(' ');
          foreach (var x in rawpaysplit){             
         
          if (x.Equals (rawpaysplit[0])){
          autopay.PId = 3;}
          if (x.Equals (rawpaysplit[1])){
          autopay.PId = tzid;}   
          if (x.Equals (rawpaysplit[2])){
          autopay.PId = 4;}
          autopay.Pay= Convert.ToDecimal(x);
          autopay.UId = id;
          autopay.Tcd = tcd;
          autopay.PDate = DateTime.Now;
          autopay.LastUpdate = DateTime.Now;
            autopay.PEntryId = Membership.GetUser().UserName;
            db.AutoPays.Add(autopay);
          
            db.SaveChanges();
 }
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }
```

Model

```
 public class AutoPay
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public int? Tcd { get; set; }
    public int UId { get; set; }
    public virtual Member Member { get; set; }
    public int PId { get; set; }
    public virtual PayCat PayCat { get; set; }
    public int YId { get; set; }
    public virtual DateYear DateYear { get; set; }
    public int MId { get; set; }
    public virtual DateMonth DateMonth { get; set; }
    [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:F2}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
    [DisplayName("Amount")]
    public decimal Pay { get; set; }
    [ScaffoldColumn(false)]
    public DateTime PDate { get; set; }
    [DisplayName("Entry By")]
    public string PEntryId { get; set; }
    [DisplayName("last Upadated By")]
    public string PUpdatedBy { get; set; }
    [DisplayName("Receipt No")]
    public string RecNo { get; set; }
    [DisplayName("Book No")]
    public int BId { get; set; }
    public virtual ReceiptBook ReceiptBook { get; set; }
    public bool POK { get; set; }
    [ScaffoldColumn(false)]
    public DateTime LastUpdate { get; set; }
    public string PayCatSplit
    {
        get { return string.Format("{0} {1} {2}", Math.Round((this.Pay * 0.773211m), 2), Math.Round((this.Pay * 0.123703m),2), Math.Round((this.Pay * 0.103086m))); }
    }
```

I passed a lot of the variables in the querystring to reduce the number of fields in the views form.
I managed to do this coding but it skips the first two values and save only the last correct entry in the database.  I need experts help

Comment: post your controller and model code

Comment: @Nighil I have posted the controller and model as you requested

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Of course you can do it. On MVC you can do any programming that you normally would be able to do on other framework.

However, the paradigm of MVC pattern requires you to think in a different way of how it's usually done on more straightforward frameworks.

Here I'm going to tip you something. Don't use your controllers to make calculations or data manipulations. Just use a model class to do that and make your controller to call that class and use it, try to maintain your controllers as methods dedicated to distribute your program execution and data between views and model classes, letting those lasts the hard work.

So, of course, you can pass any data from your view to the controller, use your controller to pass this value to a model class where you made any calculation or manipulation you need on the data and save it to database.

Comment: Thanks @Bardo I am doing some more research.  At the moment I am able to achieve the goal using the conventional  mvc4 scafolding and templating but I have to insert records one at a time.  If am able to achieve what I want it will be a big plus to save users time

Comment: Try saving changes inside your loop instead of outside it. Move db.SaveChanges(); to inside of your for.

Comment: It'd be great if you could accept the answer if it solved your problem